# Error 806: Windows Server 2008 R2 Does'nt Connect Fortigate's VPN Server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn

We have a Fortigate 110C.
Other clients at our office are able to connect just fine. Even android devices.

But we can't connected with Windows 2008 R2 client.

```
error 806 the vpn connection between your computer and the vpn server could not be completed
```

[image: Error 806]

What do Windows 2008 have different. 
What can we do about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we disabled PreShared key, problem is solved.